# What's happening when I use miniforge with pyenv?

Tags: python, tensorflow, zsh, pyenv, mini-forge

I'm struggling to find any documentation on this.

I started using `pyenv` a while back on my M1 Mac to manage python versions.

Recently I had some issues getting `tensorflow` installed, so followed some instructions online which recommended using `miniforge`

```sh
pyenv local miniforge
python -v venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal
```

However, I'm really not sure what this is doing. It's setting pyenv local to miniforge (rather than a python version). It's setting up a virtual environment and activating. Then using the `conda` command to install something tensorflow related, and then using pip to install some more tensorflow stuff.

What exactly is happening when I set miniforge with pyenv? I only thought you could set python versions here, and though miniforge was just an installer of sorts.

Comment: Did you reach any conclusions on this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to check out the anaconda docs.  The api is the same. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html